# Check if a Mac OS X application is present

Tags: cocoa, macos, applescript

I recall there being a Cocoa framework or AppleScript dictionary to check if an Application bundle with a specific name is installed at all, anywhere on the computer.

How do I do this? Either Cocoa, AppleScript, or command line are useful to me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use [**Launch Services**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/) to do this, specifically the function `LSFindApplicationForInfo()`.

You use it like so:

```
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

CFURLRef appURL = NULL;
OSStatus result = LSFindApplicationForInfo (
                                   kLSUnknownCreator,         //creator codes are dead, so we don't care about it
                                   CFSTR("com.apple.Safari"), //you can use the bundle ID here
                                   NULL,                      //or the name of the app here (CFSTR("Safari.app"))
                                   NULL,                      //this is used if you want an FSRef rather than a CFURLRef
                                   &appURL
                                   );
switch(result)
{
    case noErr:
        NSLog(@"the app's URL is: %@",appURL);
        break;
    case kLSApplicationNotFoundErr:
        NSLog(@"app not found");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"an error occurred: %d",result);
        break;          
}

//the CFURLRef returned from the function is retained as per the docs so we must release it
if(appURL)
    CFRelease(appURL);
```

Comment: do not forget if(appURL) before the release, in case it isn't found it will try to release an unexisting object, generating a crash

Comment: Note: LSFindApplicationForInfo seems deprecated as of 10.12. Anyone knows an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

From the command line this seems to do it:

```
> mdfind 'kMDItemContentType == "com.apple.application-bundle" && kMDItemFSName = "Google Chrome.app"'
```

Comment: Using the Spotlight API to find an app will be much slower than using Launch Services.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `lsregister`.

```
on doesAppExist(appName)
    if (do shell script "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump | grep com.apple.Safari") ¬
    contains "com.apple.Safari" then return true
end appExists
```

That's pretty fast and you can do it from other languages like Python quite easily.  You would want to play around with what you grep to make it most efficient.

Comment: You're right that it's a solution for languages that can't use native APIs. However, it would be overkill to call a command-line tool from a Cocoa app, since it just queries the very same Launch Services API.

Comment: True but the OP wasn't clear how he was using it.  Plus others will certainly find this page for some other similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy, like this:

```
appInstalled("com.apple.Safari") --> true
appInstalled("com.api.finder") --> false
appInstalled("com.apple.finder") --> true
appInstalled("org.m0k.transmission") --> true, on my Mac, Transmission.app
appInstalled("org.videolan.vlc") --> true, on my Mac, VLC.app
appInstalled("com.apple.Music") --> true, on my Mac, Music.app
appInstalled("com.apple.iTunes") --> false, on my Mac, iTunes.app

on appInstalled(bundleID)
    try
        application id bundleID
        return true
    end try
    return false
end appInstalled
```